# WPF Caliburn.Micro ActivateItem triggers, but doesn't initialize only when called from code behind with datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

In my code behind, I am trying to trigger a new activeitem when a user signs in. The ActivateItem triggers but it does not go into the code behind for the view and initialize. When triggering it from buttons on the ShellView, it triggers the method and initializes.

```
<Window x:Class="ProductivityTool.Views.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:ProductivityTool.ViewModels"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{x:Type model:ShellViewModel}"
    Title="Productivity Tool" Height="700" Width="900" MinWidth="900" MinHeight="700">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1000*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="840*" />
        
        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>



    <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">

        <Button x:Name="btnPhonebook"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="auto" Margin="10">Load page one</Button>
        <Button x:Name="LoadPageTwo"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="auto">Loadpagetwo</Button>

    </StackPanel>


    <!--content control is the main window of the ShellView, different pages are just different active items-->


    <xctk:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="textBoxLogin" Grid.Column="1" Margin="209,0,0,20" Grid.Row="2" Watermark="Enter company email or U-ID" Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="179" KeyDown="TextBoxLogin_KeyDown"/>


    <Button x:Name="Loginbtn"  Content="LOGIN" Click="LoginBtn_Click" Margin="10,0,0,20" Grid.Row="2" MaxHeight="80" MaxWidth="200" MinWidth="80" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="179" Grid.Column="1"/>



    <Label x:Name="lblSignedInAs"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="10,26,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="181"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblLogged" Content="Logged Out" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  Margin="10,0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="181"/>

    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                    x:Name="ActiveItem"/>

</Grid>
```

Here is the Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using ProductivityTool.ViewModels;
using ProductivityTool.Views;


namespace ProductivityTool.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ShellView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ShellView : Window
    {

        public ShellViewModel _viewModel; //this is needed to access methods from the view model, format _viewModel.method();

        public ShellView()
        {


            InitializeComponent();

            _viewModel = new ShellViewModel();
            DataContext = _viewModel;
        }

        private void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
           string loginCredentials;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginCredentials = textBoxLogin.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Couldn't log in because no user ID or email was entered.");
            }
            else
            {


                if (textBoxLogin.Text.Length > 8)
                {


                         string emailUID = loginCredentials + "@company.com";
                         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=source;Database=DB;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");
                         con.Open();

                            //If entered login is greater than 8, assume it's an email and compare it to email records

                         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from UProfile where Email='" + emailUID + "'", con);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                        adapter.Fill(dataSet);

                    if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        string username = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Failed to retrieve credentials from database");


                    }

                    lblLogged.Content = "Signed in as:";
                    lblSignedInAs.Content = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString(); //Display who is signed in currently

                    con.Close();

                }
                else
                {
                    //else if entered value is not greater than 8, assume it's a UID and compare it to those records

                        string emailUID = loginCredentials;
                        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=source;Database=DB;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");
                        con.Open();

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from UProfile where UID='" + emailUID + "'", con);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                        adapter.Fill(dataSet);

                    if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        string username = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Failed to retrieve credentials from database");

                    }

                    lblLogged.Content = "Signed in as:";
                    lblSignedInAs.Content = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString(); //Display who is signed in currently

                    con.Close();

                    textBoxLogin.Text = ""; //clear the text box for next time
                     
                }

                _viewModel.LoadPageTwo();
            }
        }


        //When login textbox is focus and the enter key is pressed, basically simulate a "login" button press to sign the user in
        private void TextBoxLogin_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Return)
            {
                Loginbtn.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using Caliburn.Micro;
using ProductivityTool.Models;


namespace ProductivityTool.ViewModels
{
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>
    {

        //private string _lblLogged;
        //private string lblLoggedInAs;



        public void LoadWelcomePage()
        {

            ActivateItem(new WelcomeViewModel());

            //ActivateItem(new FirstChildViewModel());
           
            
        }

        public void LoadPageTwo()
        {
            ActivateItem(new FirstChildViewModel());
        }

        

    }
}
```

So if you press a button in shellview, it triggers either LoadPage methods and it then goes to the xaml.cs and initializes. But if I use the _viewModel.LoadPage to do the same thing, the method gets triggered but does not initialize anything. Why the difference?

```
using System.Windows.Controls;


namespace ProductivityTool.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Welcome.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class WelcomeView : UserControl
    {
        public WelcomeView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

Why does calling LoadPage from a button trigger the method and initialize, but calling LoadPage from _viewModel.LoadPage only trigger the method but not initialize? With breakpoints I can see it calling the methods and then skipping passed initialization but I don't understand why they are behaving differently. Welcomeview.xaml.cs and any other -view.xaml.cs files are all identical. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: i suppose you have an error in console?

Comment: No errors, but I was looking at the output that shows the Caliburn.Micro logging and this pops up in log as it skips over the line: 

```Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'ProductivityTool.ViewModels.PhonebookViewModel..ctor'```

Using the button that actually initiallzes shows the same message, but after that it also says this:

```[Caliburn.Micro.Screen] INFO: Activating ProductivityTool.ViewModels.PhonebookViewModel.``` when it actually initializes

@Frenchy